# Executing arbitrary JS code in a MATLAB Online session

Tags: matlab, web-applications, customization, undocumented-behavior

#### TL;DR

Is it possible to get a handle to the web window containing a MATLAB Online session, from within it, to be able to execute arbitrary JS code?

---

[MATLAB Online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/) is a web-app version of MATLAB. As is the case with MATLAB UIFigures, this web-app also uses a combination of Dojo + react, so theoretically a tool like [mlapptools](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/mlapptools) (disclosure: I'm one of the authors of this tool) could be used to customize figures. However, unlike a UIFigure, which has (or at least used to have) an embedded [CEF](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef) controller which exposes an `executeJS()` function, a figure within MATLAB online (which is essentially a web page) is a simple `div` which contains an `iframe` with the figure's contents.

The undocumented method to get webwindows in a "regular" MATLAB session, `matlab.internal.webwindowmanager.instance.findAllWebwindows();` doesn't work here, and `/MATLAB/toolbox/matlab/uitools/uicomponents/components/+matlab/+ui/+internal/+controller/+platformhost/MOFigurePlatformHost.m` doesn't provide any useful hints.

An so - **is there a way to get an `executeJS` capability in MATLAB Online?**

See also:

1. [Source of the recent `bundle.app.js`](https://matlab.mathworks.com/home/0.17.1/bundle.app.js)
2. [Direct link to MATLAB Online for R2023a](https://matlab.mathworks.com/matlab/9.14.0.2228253/index-matlabonlineserver.html)
3. [Undocumented MATLAB blog: Customizing uifigures part 1](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/customizing-uifigures-part-1)